# Excel Macro Loop between 2 columns and check for empty cell and add cell VBA or C#

Tags: c#, vba, excel

[image]

Excel Macro Loop between 2 columns and check for empty cell and add cell  VBA or C# 
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as though you place the value from C in the row above where it is found. So you can do this in VBA

```
finalRow=Cells(65000,1).end(xlup).row 'get me the last row with data in col a
for i = 4 to finalRow 'loop through those rows
    if not isempty(cells(i, 3)) and isempty(cells(i, 1)) then 'if something in c, but not an for same row then
        cells(i-1, 5) = cells(i, 3) 'put c value in col e (one row up)
        cells(i, 3) = "" 'set c value to nothing
    end if
next i
```

Comment: Perfect ! thanks a lot ! any chance u give me this code on C# too ?

Comment: Glad I could help, but I'm not a C# developer. Maybe take a stab at it yourself and produce a new question with any C# code you have if you get stuck.